Buscador y Carrito
espero que puedan ayudarme. Estoy enfrentando un problema técnico con un sitio web que estoy desarrollando. El inconveniente tiene que ver con la funcionalidad de dos elementos importantes en la página: el carrito de compras y el buscador.
En particular, tengo configurado el carrito de compras utilizando JavaScript, y hasta hace poco todo funcionaba correctamente. Sin embargo, ahora cuando intento hacer clic en el ícono del buscador, este no se abre como lo hacía antes. El comportamiento era el esperado previamente, pero ahora, por alguna razón, el buscador no responde al clic.
Por otro lado, he notado que si trato de corregir este problema del buscador, el carrito de compras deja de funcionar. Es decir, cuando intento acceder al carrito después de modificar el código del buscador, simplemente no se abre, aunque el código del carrito estaba funcionando perfectamente antes.
Llevo un buen rato buscando una solución, pero no he podido encontrar la manera de que ambos elementos, el carrito de compras y el buscador, funcionen correctamente al mismo tiempo. He revisado el código y no logro identificar el conflicto entre ambos, ya que cada uno parece estar trabajando de forma independiente, pero no puedo hacer que ambos operen sin que uno interfiera con el otro.
Agradecería mucho cualquier sugerencia o solución que me puedan brindar, ya que estoy bloqueado y no logro encontrar una forma de resolver este inconveniente. Muchas gracias de antemano por su tiempo y ayuda.
este es mi html........................
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>DNX</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Vista/Css/Encabezado.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Vista/Css/ModalLogin.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Vista/Css/ModalRegistro.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC:wght@400;700&family=Economica:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header id="header">
        <img class="logo" id="Lg" src="https://fontmeme.com/permalink/241121/b37e8d2a79bb0dcb8d7f8e1b712dfea5.png" alt="DNX Logo" border="0">
        <nav>       
            <ul class="link">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" aria-label="Hombre">HOMBRE</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#" aria-label="Pantalon">Pantalon</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" aria-label="Camisa">Camisas/Camisetas</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" aria-label="Hoodie">Hoodie</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" aria-label="Mujer">MUJER</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#" aria-label="Pantalon">Pantalon</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" aria-label="Camisa">Camisas/Camisetas</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" aria-label="Hoodie">Hoodie</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" aria-label="Sale">SALE</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="cta-container">
            <img class="Buscar" id="searchIcon" src="/Vista/Img/Lupa.png" alt="Buscar">
            <img class="Perfil" id="openModal" src="/Vista/Img/Perfil.png" alt="Perfil">
            <img class="Carrito" id="cartIcon" src="/Vista/Img/Carrito.png" alt="Carrito">
        </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Segundo header para el buscador -->
    <header id="searchHeader">
        <div id="searchContainer">
            <input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Buscar...">
            <img class="search-icon" src="/Vista/Img/Lupa.png" alt="Buscar" id="searchIcon">
        </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Contenedor para el modal -->
    <div id="modalContainer" class="modal-container"></div>
    
    <!-- Contenedor del carrito -->
    <div class="showcart">
        <div class="cartab">
            <h1>Carrito</h1>
            <div class="lisCar">
                <!-- Aquí puedes agregar los elementos del carrito -->
            </div>
            <div class="btn">
                <button class="checkout">Ver todo</button>
                <button class="closes" aria-label="Cerrar carrito">X</button> <!-- Botón de cerrar -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="/Vista/Script/Encabezado.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

y este es mi js......................
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const header = document.getElementById('header');
    const searchHeader = document.getElementById('searchHeader');
    const searchInput = document.getElementById('searchInput');
    const cartContainer = document.querySelector('.showcart'); 
    const closeCartButton = document.querySelector('.closes');  
    const cartIcon = document.querySelector('.Carrito');


    if (searchHeader) {
        searchHeader.style.display = 'none';
    }


    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        header.classList.toggle('header-scrolled', window.scrollY > 10);
    });


    const openModalButton = document.getElementById('openModal');
    const modalContainer = document.getElementById('modalContainer');

    if (openModalButton) {
        openModalButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            fetch('/Vista/Html/ModalLogin.html')
                .then(response => response.text())
                .then(data => {
                    modalContainer.innerHTML = data;

                    const closeModalButton = document.querySelector('.ModalLogin .close');

   
                    if (closeModalButton) {
                        closeModalButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
                            modalContainer.innerHTML = ''; 
                        });
                    }

                    // Cerrar el modal al hacer clic en el fondo (overlay)
                    loginModal.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
                        if (event.target === loginModal) {
                            modalContainer.innerHTML = ''; 
                        }
                    });
                })
                .catch(error => console.error('Error al cargar el modal:', error));
        });
    }


    const searchIcon = document.getElementById('searchIcon');

    if (searchIcon) {
        searchIcon.addEventListener('click', () => {
            if (searchHeader.style.display === 'none' || searchHeader.style.display === '') {
                searchHeader.style.display = 'flex'; 
                searchInput.focus();
                header.classList.add('search-active'); 
            } else {
                searchHeader.style.display = 'none'; 
                header.classList.remove('search-active'); 
            }
        });
    }


    if (cartIcon) {
        cartIcon.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            event.stopPropagation(); 
            if (cartContainer.style.right === '0px') {
                cartContainer.style.right = '-300px'; 
                header.classList.remove('header-cart-active'); 
            } else {
                cartContainer.style.right = '0px'; 
                header.classList.add('header-cart-active'); 
            }
        });
    }


    if (closeCartButton) {
        closeCartButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            cartContainer.style.right = '-300px'; 
            header.classList.remove('header-cart-active'); 
        });
    }


    document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        const isClickInsideCart = cartContainer.contains(event.target);
        const isClickOnCartIcon = cartIcon.contains(event.target);


        if (!isClickInsideCart && !isClickOnCartIcon) {
            cartContainer.style.right = '-300px';
            header.classList.remove('header-cart-active'); 
        }
    });
});


No se yo si la repetición del id="searchIcon" te estará provocando parte del problema.  Lo estás usando en dos elementos distintos, y el javascript solo te va a interpretar el primero de ellos, pasando del segundo.

gracias al parecer era eso ya me funciona
